# Почему таблица bootstrap находится внизу?

Tags: html, bootstrap

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
              <td>Francisco Chang</td>
              <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

https://codepen.io/kostyabagr/pen/oNddEPr  вот ссылка на код, почему то таблица на вкладке 'характеристики' находится внизу. Если отключить css файл, то таблица встает на свое место, но я не понимаю, что надо исправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

браузер видит, но не отображает таблицу

**Спасибо за помощь**

Comment: Не стоит верстать на таблицах.. Мы же не в древнем египте..

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что вы не закрыли многие теги `tr` `td` `table`.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, спасибо за рекомендацию, но я не занимаюсь front end разработкой и таких тонкостей не знаю. Я делаю pet project(интернет магазин) и хотел использовать таблицу , что бы показать характеристики ноутбука

Comment: Для характеристик еще окей, но у вас эти характеристики находятся в еще двух таблицах..